# JSP displaying source code instead of executing

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm new to jsp and have ran into some trouble.  Initially, the jsp file and associated java classes were built and tested fine on a test Tomcat server.  Now, they've been transitioned to another server of what I believe is the same setup (except it's linux now instead of windows).  But when the jsp page is accessed the source code is displayed instead of the jsp actually executing.  I've googled for a while but received no success.

Here is the code of the jsp file I am testing:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello!  The time is now <%= new java.util.Date() %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And here is what I see in my browser when navigating to the page:

```
 Hello! The time is now <%= new java.util.Date() %>
```

The source of the page is the exact code that is typed in the example file:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello!  The time is now <%= new java.util.Date() %>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The server appears to be working.  Here are is the response headers I obtained from Firebug:

```
Date    Sat, 15 Jan 2011 20:53:24 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Last-Modified   Sat, 15 Jan 2011 02:20:18 GMT
Etag    "b385d8-55-499d931205c80"
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  85
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I had thought that [this page](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/InvokerServlet) might solve the problem since there was no reference to the jsp file I was using or even the following snippets in my web.xml file in the WEB-INF folder:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logVerbosityLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>WARNING</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried inserting these lines and restarting Tomcat, but no success.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the request actually reaches Tomcat? Is there another webserver in front? How about servlets? Do they work?

Comment: What exactly do you have in the JSP and what exactly are you seeing in browser? What exactly is in the HTML source? (rightclick in browser, choose *View Source*) I'd be interested what exactly you mean with "source code". JSP tags? JSTL tags? EL? Scriptlets? Or even HTML? You don't need to post the full code, just the minimal JSP file which exhibits the behaviour is sufficient.

Comment: @Thilo: if the request didn't reach Tomcat, he wouldn't have seen anything from the JSP, let alone source code. I however expect that the OP isn't that unobviously dumb to drop JSP files in the another webserver instead of Tomcat :)

Comment: When I enter in the address of the jsp file in the browser the source code of the jsp file is displayed instead of the jsp executing.  Here are the first few lines of what I see in the browser:
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
%><%@ page import="java.io.*"
%><%@ page import="java.lang.*"
%><%@ page import="java.util.Date"
...

Comment: I've had issues with the url-pattern in the past.  Try generalizing it to just * and see if that helps.  Also, make sure you're not getting any console warning messages when you start up Tomcat like "SEVERE..." which usually indicates a key configuration failed or library was missing, which also might be the root cause.

Comment: @DJStroky: This is still not detailed enough. Do you see it like that in the browser screen or in the HTML source? If in the browser screen, then it would mean that it's been sent as `text/plain` or that the `<` and `>` and so on are been HTML-escaped somehow (you should then see `&lt;` and `&gt;` and so on in the page source). Also, I'd be interested to know what exactly the HTTP response headers contains. Please edit your question to add answers on *all* the questions I asked in this and previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the response headers:

> Server  Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

This is not served by [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org), but by [Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org). You did not deploy it to Tomcat at all.

Comment: "@Thilo: if the request didn't reach Tomcat, he wouldn't have seen anything from the JSP, let alone source code. I however expect that the OP isn't that unobviously dumb to drop JSP files in the another webserver instead of Tomcat :) " :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have just had this same problem, which is how I stumbled on this post.  For me, it turned out that the issue was the difference between CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE.  I think a lot of people don't realize this is two different places.  On my Ubuntu, CATALINA_HOME was in /usr/share/tomcat6 but CATALINA_BASE was in /var/lib/tomcat6.  It matters because you need to put your jsp files in CATALINA_BASE.  So, in fact, I would say that Tomcat was not finding your code, even though your browser found the file and happily displayed it for you as it does other text files.

Hope this helps someone else who comes here with the same problem--it's my first attempt to post an answer on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

See where it says "logVerbosityLevel" and "WARNING"?  Change WARNING to DEBUG.  You can also find your catalina.sh script and find your java command and make sure the flag -DDEBUG is included in the startup options.

Looking in your log with full debug mode on will tell you if there are any problems starting Tomcat on the new server.

For instance, you could have a missing depencency or a dependency conflict that isn't showing up with less informative logging levels.

Lastly, have you tried a simple JSP test page?

```
      <% out.println("Hello"); %>
```

If you put that in a JSP and try to load it, do you see the JSP or the output?

Have you tried using the Tomcat port in your request?  Usually, this is 8080.  I think one of the commentors mentioned that as a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Migration java 6 --> 8, tomcat 5 --> 8
if you have had something like this in **app** web.xml

```
<!--need this so that this work:  jsp:include page="WEB-INF...xxx.jspf-->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

that would produce **JSP displaying source code instead of executing** at tomcat 8 as it seems it rolls over the thing about jsp inside tomcat web xml.

Solution is to erase this code in **app** web.xml and put everything into **tomcat** web.xml, like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```