# JSP page is displayed as text instead of compiling

Tags: spring, jsp

[Here is the screenshot of my problem for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hork2.png)

The content type in the headers is text/html and according to my research, the above error could be because the content type is text/plain. 
    Can anyone please help me with this ? Following is the source code of the jsp file.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring MVC Tutorial by Crunchify - Hello World Spring MVC Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
   background-image: url('http://crunchify.com/bg.png');
}
</style>
</head> 
<body>${message}

    <br>
   <br>
<div style="font-family: verdana; padding: 10px; border-radius: 10px; font-size: 12px; text-align:center;">

    Spring MCV Tutorial by <a href="http://crunchify.com">Crunchify</a>.
        Click <a
        href="http://crunchify.com/category/java-web-development-tutorial/"
        target="_blank">here</a> for all Java and <a
        href='http://crunchify.com/category/spring-mvc/' target='_blank'>here</a>
       for all Spring MVC, Web Development examples.<br>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think screenshot is missing?

Comment: Did you deploy your application to the tomcat server you downloaded? This similar question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697654/jsp-displaying-source-code-instead-of-executing

Comment: @BurakKeceli : The screen shot is at the link 
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hork2.png .
Can you please refer it as for some reason I am not able to attach it in the comment.

Comment: @dev_feed : Yes I have deployed it on tomcat7 which is embedded in eclipse. But still I cant find the reason why the problem occurs. Moreover, I just started developing web applications last week , I am not exactly sure how to debug the container. Any suggestions and methods to debug this issue would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors in your eclipse "console" view? Whenever you start tomcat, it should open the console view and log information.  Another helpful item here would be to add your spring controller and configuration to your question.