# Tomcat8 Spring MVC4 maven jsp source code displayed instead of content

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, maven-3, tomcat8

I am trying to build and deploy the Spring MVC web application from My MacBook Air. Created the maven project and added all the necessary files for the project. Able to build the project and deploy to Tomcat 8 via maven pom.xml. When I access the page it just shows me the jsp code as it is instead of content.

I could not able to see the generated servlet file out tomcat work folder. Since am deploying the files via maven I don't think it can hide in my eclipse workspace.

I went through similar questions but none of them worked out the form. For example, there were some suggestions to add / in front of  WEB -INF in servlet.xml and add the  tags in JSP and also put the content inside of the body tag. I hope this is something to do with my Tomcat8 and Maven3.3.9

When I access the application with URL, I can see the logs inside of my controller so it means that my code is deployed into Tomcat but only JSP to servlet conversion is not happening.

Here are my configuration files.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Digital Services</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>digitalservices</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/digitalservices-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>digitalservices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**ditalservices-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rajan.myservices.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- 
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
        id="tilesViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    </bean>
    -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Maven POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rajan.myservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>DigitalServices</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DigitalServices Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <apachetiles.version>3.0.5</apachetiles.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Below declared dependencies are included for the servers who may complain 
            about servlet/jstl missing dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>DigitalServices</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <username>tomcat</username>
                    <password>tomcat1</password>
                    <path>/DigitalServices</path>
                    <update>true</update>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Controller Class**

```
package com.rajan.myservices.controller;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.rajan.myservices.model.Person;


@Controller
public class HomePageController {

    @RequestMapping(value="index")
    public String index() {
        System.out.println("In index");
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="viewPerson")
    public ModelAndView viewPersons(Model model) {
        Map<String, List<Person>> persons = 
                new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();
        System.out.println("In View Person");
        persons.put("persons", Person.createPersons());
        System.out.println("persons: "+persons);
        return new ModelAndView("personList", persons);
    }

}
```

**Index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="margin:10px;">
    <h3>Welcome to Digital Services by <% out.println("Hello Test"); %></h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Jsp output when acccess the application using http://localhost:8080/DigitalServices/index

```
Welcome to Digital Services by <% out.println("Hello Test"); %>
```

FYI - I can see those sysouts from Controller class in catalina.out.

Comment: `return "index";` means there should be an `index.jsp` file, not `Index.jsp` file. Better implement `apachetiles` config. You are just added the dependency not configured.

Comment: Hi Sumesh, thank you so much for providing suggestion continuously. Originally I started with apache tiles with Spring4. Looks like apache tiles is not fully supported in spring version 4 and it creates other kind of problem if I downgrade my spring version. So left that part for now and started to implement very basic version of mvc first then move on step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Put below line in your jsp file.

```
<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then refer this [JSP displaying source code instead of executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697654/jsp-displaying-source-code-instead-of-executing)

Comment: still same response after adding the jsp page directive. Highlighted link didn't have any accepted solution. I tried to make sure that htmls are closed properly as suggested in the link.

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You are using pure HTML in JSP file so snippets won't compile. You are missing page directive. The page directive is used to provide instructions to the container that pertain to the current JSP page. You may code the page directives anywhere in your JSP page. By convention, page directives are coded at the top of the JSP page.

Following is the basic syntax of page directive − `<%@ page attribute = "value" %>`

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div style="margin:10px;">
        <h3>Welcome to Digital Services by <% out.println("Hello Test"); %></h3>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: no error in the console of tomcat as well as browser. I can see the log statements from the java methods of the controller class.

Comment: @RaguVenkatesan You seem to have version conflict. In your servlet.xml `spring-beans-3.2.xsd ` which represents spring version 3.2 but in `pom.xml `you mentioned `spring 4`. In your local machine there may be spring 3.2 downloaded  in m2 folder.

Comment: Thank you Sumesh. I missed to see this version conflict, I will try and  update the status here asap.

Comment: I changed the schema definition from 3.2 to 4.0 as my Spring version is 4.0.3. Updated the project, built, un deployed the existing application then deployed. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: @RaguVenkatesan Use version less xsd . It will automatically choose current version. Refer this http://www.springframework.org/schema/ for existing xsd versions.

Comment: yes I did verified the schema version in the above link then decided to use 4.0. Beyond this, do you think that jsp is not getting compiled due to this mismtch. It doesnt give any error when I build it , and I can see the log output from my controller class when I hit the URL. From log I can understand that controller class method is invoked. Only rendering the UI has problem. What do you think?

Comment: @RaguVenkatesan Tile configuration or ViewResolver not configured properly... Are you getting 404 in the front end? Also, you should specify resource(CSS, js files) location in the configuration.

Comment: not 404 instead i am getting the jsp page as it is in the browser. Could you please elaborate on what I am missing on the CSS or js file configuration?

Comment: Are you using spring secuirty?

Comment: No, am not using Spring security.

Comment: Is it a maven project? Show the project structure.

Comment: Hi Sumesh, here is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JrHHottADokwbVOtanezKWGTxjQfaOIH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh @RaguVenkatesan you are implementing spring boot let me check.

Comment: I couldn't find your configuration class. If it is for learning pupose use spring initializer to create pre configured spring boot application.

Comment: Hi Sumesh, not sure how you decided this as Spring boot, its just plain web application using spring mvc. actually I tried for apche tiles and it didnt work well, so just trying for plain mvc with spring. You can refer the configurations from the original post.

Comment: Your are using spring tool suit   or sts eclipse plugin so why you go for spring mvc it is too old now. Learn spring boot with mvc design pattern.

Comment: am not using spring tool site instead eclipse oxygen. Anyway I was not looking for spring boot instead just mvc. I will continue to find the problem. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Finally, i found the root cause of this issue. It was due to url pattern in web.xml.

Comment: Originally I gave /* in the url pattern (refer my post) of web.xml, just removed the wild card it worked.

Comment: Please ask genuine questions.

Comment: It is  valid question and I was struggling with that for almost two weeks. I have provided my entire web.xml in my original post, some how it was not identified. Also I just did this on a trial and error basis to fix the problem. Anyway thanks for your different suggestion to fix this problem in the past.

Comment: You must go through online tutorials no one do that silly error. Give the link that you referred to do this project.

Comment: Hello Sumesh. This is not a silly mistake for me, if you feel so please ignore this. I believe lot of quesitions raised on the URL pattern in stackoverflow.